# How to use instance chain to solve overlapping

Tags: purescript

I've been trying next purescript ver 0.12.0-rc1.
I have a question how to use new feature 'instance chain'.
in my understanding the instance chain provides a feature to be able to specify instance resolving order explicitly. this solves avoid instance definition overlapping.

so I suppose it may work:

```
class A a
class B b
class C c where
  c :: c -> String

instance ca :: A a => C a where
  c = const "ca"
else
instance cb :: B b => C b where
  c = const "cb"

data X = X
instance bx :: B X

main :: forall eff. Eff (console :: CONSOLE | eff) Unit
main = logShow $ c X
```

but cannot compiled.

what is not correctly?
or what is the instance chain usage?

result:

```
Error found:
in module Main
at src/Main.purs line 23, column 8 - line 23, column 20

  No type class instance was found for

Main.A X


while applying a function c
  of type C t0 => t0 -> String
  to argument X
while inferring the type of c X
in value declaration main

where t0 is an unknown type
```

Comment: It is currently an open issue: https://github.com/purescript/purescript/issues/3120

Comment: I hadn't read it. that's what I want!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even with instance chains matching is still done on the head of an instance. There is no "backtracking" when any of constraint fails for the chosen instance.

Your instances are completely overlapping on the head, so your first instance always matches before second one and it fails because there is no `A` instance for `X`.

Instance chains allows you to define explicit ordering of instance resolution without relying on for example alphabetical ordering of names etc. (as it was done till 0.12.0 version - [please check the third paragraph here](https://github.com/purescript/documentation/blob/77745cf220945a177ac367cf085b41524e655898/language/Type-Classes.md)). For example you can define this overlapping scenario:

```hs
class IsRecord a where
   isRecord :: a -> Boolean

instance a_isRecordRecord :: IsRecord (Record a) where
   isRecord _ = true

instance b_isRecordOther :: IsRecord a where
   isRecord _ = false
```

as

```hs
instance isRecordRecord :: IsRecord (Record a) where
   isRecord _ = true
else instance isRecordOther :: IsRecord a where
   isRecord _ = false
```

I hope it compiles - I don't have `purs-0.12.0-rc` yet ;-)

Comment: oh, does constraints not help select instance even if use instance chains? ok i understand. Thanks! :)